# Is jumping back in streams safe? (std::ifstream, std::ofstream)

Tags: c++, iostream

Case A. I need to look for something in an istream, then possibly jump back to start over.

Case B. I need to write to an ostream, then sometimes jump back some chars to overwrite stuff.

Are the following pieces of code safe? (i.e. guaranteed not to crash)

```
// Case A
std::ifstream Stream; // or std::istringstream Stream
// save position
auto initial_position = Stream.tellg();
// Read some characters
while ( ... ) { Stream.get(); ... }
// jump back
Stream.seekg( initial_position );
```

```
// Case B
std::ofstream Stream; // or std::ostringstream Stream
// save position
auto initial_position = Stream.tellp();
// Write some characters
while ( ... ) { Stream.put(); ... }
// jump back
Stream.seekp( initial_position );
```

Notes:

1. I guess performance might suffer if we jumped back to a position that has already been 'discarded from memory' (for istream) or flushed to disk (for ostream), but I guess that's a rare case anyway. Is there a way to prevent the worst case?
2. I don't want to (and basically can't) use an intermediate string to do the reads or writes on.
3. My code has been working fine for everything I have done so far, I am just worried that it might break/crash under certain unknown circumstances

Comment: Depends on the stream. Some streams have no memory. For example, one you write a byte onto a wire, it's gone. You can't call it back, and storing all of the data sent down that wire could be prohibitively expensive after the device has been running for a few years..

Comment: @user4581301 That's why I was asking specifically for the std::iostreams mentioned. If seekg and seekp are given, one could think it is OK to use them.

Comment: I'll have to go Standard-diving to see if there are guarantees, but I have a lot of code that won't work if you can't seek back in a file stream that actually fronts a file. Note that in Unix, a file stream could represent a serial port, and the serial port, at its simplest, is just a wire.

Comment: Happy hunting. Hope you don't have to dive in serial ports, the water must be awful there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a reason it is called a stream - something you can only read or write once. As in "No man ever steps in the same river twice, for it's not the same river and he's not the same man." (replace "river" with "stream").

Streams backed by files do provide random access, but that is more of an exception. Also, the file could be truncated and/or rewritten while you read it, so that you might not be able to seek back or forward in the file stream you just read.

The most practical parsing algorithms only ever examine each byte of input once and in sequence - that makes them suitable for use with any stream, e.g. file, pipe, socket. You may like to implement your parsing in this fashion.

There are other parsing algorithms that are most efficient when they can seek the input back and forth. For those algorithms the preferred way is to map the entire file or specific parts of it into memory.

Comment: Thanks. Pretty good tips and in style! I like the "You may like to..." Actually pretty easy to extract the part that I need, seems like I just had a mental block against it there...

Comment: Actually pretty hard, because I have to reuse the part if it does not match. My block was justified.

Comment: Still came to the conclusion, that it is not safe to go back, despite the absence of  explicit warnings in the docs.